# Sending an OWA logon form from Java

Tags: java, forms, dom, outlook-web-app

I am interested in a way to programmatically log into OWA (Microsoft Outlook Web Access - a web-based email client) from Java code and retrieve nothing more than the inbox unread count -- I can read this number from the inbox web page's HTML source - but the problem is getting there - logging in.

Essentially, from looking at the HTML source of the OWA logon page, I can see that there is an HTML form element:

```
<form action="owaauth.dll" method="POST" name="logonForm" autocomplete="off">
```

that gets submitted by a button element within it:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Log On" onclick="clkLgn()">
```

From investigating the clkLgn() script, I find that it sends a cookie to the document so it may not be crucial:

```
function clkLgn()
{
    if(gbid("rdoPrvt").checked)
    {
        var oD=new Date();
        oD.setTime(oD.getTime()+2*7*24*60*60*1000);
        var sA="acc="+(gbid("chkBsc").checked?1:0);
        var sL="lgn="+gbid("username").value;
        document.cookie="logondata="+sA+"&"+sL+";expires="+oD.toUTCString();
    }
}
```

Basically, how can I send this form?
The following code is my attempt at the problem, I can make the HTTP connection - but I can't seem to be able to POST the correct HTTP request.

```
                URL urlObject = new URL(url);

                HttpURLConnection hConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlObject.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
                hConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                hConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(hConnection.getOutputStream());

                ps.print("username="+username+"&amp;password="+password);
                ps.close();


                hConnection.connect();

                if( HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == hConnection.getResponseCode() )
                {
                    InputStream is = hConnection.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.html");
                    int data;
                    while((data=is.read()) != -1)
                    {
                      os.write(data);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    os.close();
                    hConnection.disconnect();
                }
```

It just keeps returning the same logon HTML page.

Comment: OWA and Sharepoint both like to use hidden fields for "security". Grab a toolbar for your browser that will show form fields and post a listing of all the fields and their values. Clear cookies, refresh the page, and post that information again to see what changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That JavaScript does certainly an important thing: it adds a cookie to the document. A decent HTTP client is required to send all valid cookies along the headers on every HTTP request. You should do the same programmatically. You can add headers using [`URLConnection#setRequestProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Further, there are several things to take into account as well when submitting forms programmatically: you should not skip any hidden input fields (`input type="hidden"`), those might be of relevance. You should also send the `name=value` pair of the submit button you'd like to press programmatically along as request parameter. Finally, you should not be using `&amp;` to concatenate parameter pairs, but `&`.

Note that I don't guarantee that it will finally work, that OWA thing might have some other prevention against bots, but it should solve the as far spotted problems.

#### See also:

- [How to use URLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

---

By the way, have you considered just connecting it using a SMTP/IMAP API like [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)?

Comment: Good link!
How do I trigger that onClick() event on the input button then?
Does sending the POST HTTP request trigger the event implicitly?

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything with the HTML page or the JS code. You just send exactly the parameters and cookies which the server side expects.

Answer (score 1):

Why go through a form? MS recently open sourced a Java client for their Exchange server API.

http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/28/open-sourcing-exchange-web-services-ews-java-api/

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api