# How to use javamail to connect to ms exchange webmail?

Tags: java

I checked that I am not able to access the pop 3 port and imap port. I think I can only access via https webmail.

So for this case how do I actually connect to the microsoft exchange server and read the emails inside using java mail can anyone provide any specific code samples to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to Exchange via OWA sounds like its going to be difficult; [here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283785/sending-an-owa-logon-form-from-java) which deals with at least the authentication side of things.

In any event, you can connect to an Exchange server via IMAP if the IMAP service is turned on.  Check with your server admin to confirm the service is running.  If it is running, [see this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713116/javamail-exchange-authentication) for how to set connection parameters.